# telnet Unix/Linux and download the file to local Windows system

Tags: linux

Is it possible to do so:

I am on Windows system and telnet Unix/Linux remotely. Then I would like to download file from telnet mode and download to Windows system. Any Unix/Linux command are able to do so? like rcp  or ftp. How to do so? Does it require any configuration on both system?

i try to write the shell script on Unix/linux side. and i telnet Unix/linux system remotely from local Windows machine and log in to Unix/linux system, run the script on Unix/linux side. some files will be transfered or download automatically to my windows system.

assume permission is not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually people use ftp session to transfer files. If permissions is not a problem why don't you run ftp from your Windows computer?

You can create a windows batch script to load your file. Try something like

```
ftp hostname
user
password
cd /path/to/file
get myfile
quit
```

Comment: hey Oleg Pavliv. i try to write the shell script on Unix/linux side. and i telnet from local Windows machine and log in to Unix/linux system, run the script. some files will be transfered automatically to my windows system. Is that possible ?

Comment: I added some info to my answer

Comment: How about executing the shell script on Unix/Linux side rather than run the batch on windows. and Unix/Linux remote machine will send file to windows machine. Is is feasible? any solution.

Comment: You can run the same script (just replace get with put) on unix if you have ftp server installed on your windows computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use x/y/zmodem to transfer file if both ends support that.

On Linux/Unix, you can use sz command to send file via zmodem.

On Windows, both Secure CRT (commercial) or Le Putty (open source) are capable of zmodem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (command line) or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) (GUI).

Comment: hey jterrace thank you for ur reply. so is it possible done in telnet mode from windows?. yes i putty can do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it through the existing connection, look at protocols such as ZMODEM and the `rz` and `sz` commands for them on Linux.  You will need a terminal program on Windows that supports that protocol though.

Comment: so it cannot simply be done by using telnet mode from windows system, and rcp or ftp on Unix/linux system?

Comment: @user380690: What can you and can't you install on each side?  Why not use scp or sftp like the other answers are suggesting?  You really shouldn't be using telnet anyway (use ssh instead).

Comment: thank you Jeremiah Willcock. i used to do like that. just curious whether it is feasible from telnet mode ;)

Answer (score 0):

For small files, I just uuencode (or gzip -c | uuencode name.gz)  on the command line over the telnet session, then cut and paste to uudecode on my local windows computer (using cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
telnet hostname 80 > filename_to_download_in
GET /path/to/file HTTP/1.0
```